# Как правильно задать transition для z-index?

Tags: css

Есть несколько карточек, они частично лежат друг на друге. Как сделать так чтобы при наведении на карточку она появлялась перед всеми карточками плавно, а не быстро?

Comment: ваш код думаю поможет разобратся что неработает у вас.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384799/how-to-transition-z-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Анимация z-index эффекта не даст. Можно использовать, например, `opacity`. Зависит от назначения этих блоков

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.card.first {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: green
}
.card.second {
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: blue
}
.card.second.shadow {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s
}
.cards:hover .card.second.shadow {
  opacity: 0
 }
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card first"></div>
  <div class="card second"></div>
  <div class="card second shadow"></div>
</div>
```